# How do I use Arrays to store information?

Tags: java

How do I use Arrays to store taxpayer information? Say I want to enter information for 3 taxpayers. How can I use arrays to store the first name, last name, gross income, etc. three times?

```
numTaxpayers = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many taxpayers would you like to calculate taxes for?"));
do
{
    firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your first name?");
    lastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your last name?");
    grossIncome = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your gross income?"));
    numChildren = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many children do you have?"));
    taxDependency = numChildren * 3000;
    taxableIncome = grossIncome - taxDependency;
    name = firstName + " " + lastName;
    tax = calculateTax(taxableIncome);
    message += "First Name: " + firstName + "\nLast Name: " + lastName + "\nGross Income: $" + String.format("%.2f",grossIncome) + "\nNumber of Children: " + numChildren + "\nTax Due: $" + String.format("%.2f",tax) + "\n\n";
    count ++;
} while (count <= numTaxpayers);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,message);
```

Comment: Create class Taxpayer to include all details and store instances of that class in your array

Comment: You don't need to ask this on Stack Overflow. This information is easily available on the web and there is an official tutorial that covers it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Rolled back to first revision. @Dan Please don't vandalize your own posts; it's frowned upon and can lead to question bans.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to define a `Taxpayer` class that has those fields and then make an array of them, that is to say, a `Taxpayer[]`. Though you'd probably be better off with a `List<Taxpayer>` or something like that; it'll give you greater flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either a multidimensional array of objects or an array of length 3 * number of taxpayers. But a better option will be to create a TaxPayer class and store that into an array(Taxpayer[]) or collection(Collection).

Comment: What if instead of 3 taxpayers it will be a random number?

Comment: I said 3 * number of taxpayers because taxpayer has 3 fields, but you can have any number of taxpayers.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class called TaxPayer like this:

```
class TaxPayer{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    ...
}
...
do
{
    firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your first name?");
    lastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your last name?");
    grossIncome = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your gross     income?"));
    numChildren = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many children do you have?"));
    taxDependency = numChildren * 3000;
    taxableIncome = grossIncome - taxDependency;
    name = firstName + " " + lastName;
    tax = calculateTax(taxableIncome);
    message += "First Name: " + firstName + "\nLast Name: " + lastName + "\nGross Income: $" + String.format("%.2f",grossIncome) + "\nNumber of Children: " + numChildren + "\nTax Due: $" + String.format("%.2f",tax) + "\n\n";
    arr[count] = new TaxPayer(firstName, lastName, ...);
    count ++;
} while (count <= numTaxpayers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a class like this:

```
Class TaxPayer{
 String fName;
 String lName;
 int gross;

 public TaxPayer(String fName,String lName, int gross){
  this.fName=fName;
  this.lName=lName;
  this.gross=gross;
 }

}
```

Now, I can use it as,

```
List<TaxPayer> arr=new List<TaxPayer>();

TaxPayer payer1=new TaxPayer("Nicol","Mick",5000);
arr.add(payer1);

TaxPayer payer2=new TaxPayer("Mark","Tylor",5000);
arr.add(payer2);

// for retrieving values, use like
String payer1name= arr.get(0).fName;
```